# Using different folders with play asset delivery

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to implement Play Asset Delivery for my Android app. The basic implementation (of on-demand delivery) is done. My folder structure looks something like this:

- on_demand

  - folder1
  - folder2

Both these sub-folders contain some files that are installed on-demand. Is there a way I can have contents of only folder1 installed and skip the other?

Comment: If I understand your question, I think you want to make two separate asset packs. Then install on-demand independently when needed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have been misled by the fact that in most of the examples, the name "on_demand" is used for on demand assets.
your don't need a directory called "on_demand".
Your project structure should be something like:

- Your_project

  - app
  - gradle
  - folder1(your first on-demand asset)
  - folder2(your second on-demand asset)

To download only folder1, add only folder1 to your assetPackList and then call something like:

```
assetPackManager.fetch(assetPackList);
```

along with eveything else you need to implement for Play Asset Delivery.